# Java dbUnit CRUD test error

Tags: java, database, testing, junit, dbunit

well I 've been facing a very frustrating problem when trying to test a crud operation in an SQL Server.
Note that I use a combination of hibernate,dbunit,ms sql server2008r2 and jpa.

So, as I mentioned before I try to use dbunit to test CRUD operations. Following the documentation of dbunit, I create an XML file with the records necessary and another one to compare at the end of the operation.
In my case, the initial xml contains just two lines which also represent the relationship between my entities.
Initial xml

```
<xml> 
 <A id="1" name="nameA"/> 
 <B id="1" name="nameB" A_id="1">
</xml>
```

Expected results

```
<xml> 
 <A id="1" name="nameA"/> 
 <B id="1" name="nameB" A_id="1">
 <B id="2" name="nameBB" A_id="1">
</xml>
```

Note that we have set only the set up operation under the clean insert strategy, while the teardown operation is not defined, by default is none.

So when i try to insert another record in table b with a reference to table A, it goes OK if the database is clean. However, every time we attempt to re-execute the same test, it goes on error due to foreign key constraint violation.
In theory, dbunit each time it goes to insert the data retrieved from the xml, should (following the **clean insert strategy**) delete in reverse order and then insert the records.
However, as mentioned before, it does not delete the records indicating the foreing key violation, which leads me to think that the reverse order is not really working.

Any ideas?
tnx in advance

Comment: Could you show the code you use to do the testcase setup?

Answer (score 0):

Three ideas:

ONE: maybe you should close the tag 'B':

```
<B id="1" name="nameB" A_id="1">
```

should be (missing "/" in the end)

```
<B id="1" name="nameB" A_id="1"/>
```

TWO: you could check that you application did not add rows in other tables. e.g. C which references B or A

THREE: you could check whether there are any open transactions